# Using Tor to comment on blogs and forums?

Tags: anonymity

I am new to Tor. Can I use it to post comments on blogs, forums, and websites that have contact forms please? I would like to be able to use Tor all the time, rather than have to stop using it every time I want to make a comment, or use a contact us form.

I downloaded it today, and have been testing it out. I could not make comments on blog sites, and tried using a contact us form on a website and it failed. I have not tried to use it on forums yet, but thought I should ask. I post on forums and would love to keep my identity(IP) private. Thank you.

Comment: Needed an answer to this, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use Tor to do whatever you can do on the web, including commenting on blogs, forums, ... As long as they do not block Tor exit relays (for example you wont be able to 'comment' on Wikipedia using Tor).

So it largely depends on which blogs, forums, ... are in question, and what their policy concerning exit relays is.